# 3d scatter plot is displaying a black window

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d, matplotlib-3d, scatter3d

Here is an example of matplotlib displaying a black window on my local environment.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig, elev=4, azim=-95)
xs, ys, zs = np.linspace(-2, 2, 60), np.linspace(-2, 2, 60), np.linspace(-2, 2, 60)
ax.scatter(xs=xs, ys=xs, zs=xs)
plt.show()
```

I know the issue is not my backend as others have reported, since I can run the snippet at this site fine:

https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/mplot3d/subplot3d_demo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d', elev=4, azim=-95)` not `ax = Axes3D(fig, elev=4, azim=-95)`, just like it shows in the [example](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/mplot3d/subplot3d_demo.html).
- **Tested in `python 3.11.3`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d', elev=4, azim=-95)

xs, ys, zs = np.linspace(-2, 2, 60), np.linspace(-2, 2, 60), np.linspace(-2, 2, 60)
ax.scatter(xs=xs, ys=xs, zs=xs)
plt.show()
```

[image]